# SQL Server : find upcoming dates

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server database with a `Date` column. These dates are all future dates.

How would I go about finding all approaching dates within a 2 week time period? Basically a two week notice query on upcoming dates.

For example: Today is August 2nd. The query would return, if any, dates that were August 16th (2 weeks ahead).

And if it was run tomorrow it would return August 16th and August 17th (2 weeks ahead).

This would obviously be run everyday via a reporting manager (SSRS). Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateField BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(week, 2, GETDATE())
```

If your column is `datetime`, you may want to convert it to be a date first, otherwise running this at 12:00 on Aug 1st would return everything upto 12:00 on Aug 15th.  The following code will do this for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(MyDateField AS date) BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AND CAST(DATEADD(week, 2, GETDATE()) AS date)
```

Comment: Requirements do not specify, but I'm assuming they want the entire day. If you run this at 00:00:01, it will not return any records for the remainder of the future day.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dateCol BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AND 
    DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(wk, 2, GETDATE())), 0)))
```

This will return anything between the start of today and the end of the day in 2 weeks.

If you are trying to return any records for a single day (00:00:00 > 23:59:59) 2 weeks from today, then use

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dateCol BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(wk, 2, GETDATE()))) AND 
    DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(wk, 2, GETDATE())), 0)))
```

You can replace `GETDATE()` with whatever date you want to start/end with.

Comment: You can eliminate the time part a lot easier by casting it to a `date` type.